# Sorting corresponding lists

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

First - what I am aiming to do: I want to generate a bar chart in matplotlib and I get my data from a Django model.

In order to have an interpreted set of data I have to multiply them with data from an other model. This is why I can not sort via the queryset (at least I think I can't)

This leaves me with two lists (for each year): The Labels - Strings - and the Data - Floats -

Easy enough I can sort the Data with `sort(data)` but this obviously doesn't change the order of the labels.

The first thing that came to my mind where dictionaries, which like tuples are immutable.

Well there is a way to order dictionary - [collections](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is an amazing library - but what bothers me is that i have to pack a dictionary than have to order it via

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
```

And then unpack it again in two lists to hand it over to the function

```
matplotlib.bar(x, values, labels=keys)
```

This seems for me is highly inelegant and I have to do this 4 times (4 years of data)

How would you tackle this problem?

**Edit**:
More Info about the Django Models (a sketch ;) )

```
class EnergieSource(Models):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      co2 = models.FloatField('CO²-Equivalent')
class EnergieUsage(Models):
      date = models.DateField('Year')
      energiesource = models.ForeignKeyField(EnergieSource)
      usage = models.FloatField('Yearly use in MWh')
```

No I multiply `usage` with the `co2` and depending on the EnergySource this alters the data.

Comment: You can just `zip` to two-tuples `(label, data)`.

Comment: I hoped there is a way to just say e.g Mathplotlib order my bars and labels or hey django give me something which solves my problem - so I added the tags ;)

Comment: hehe, well no, but it's really easy anyway.. you just `myitems = dict(zip(labels,values))`, sort and then pass `myitems.keys()` and `myitems.values()` to matplotlib - nothing ugly or inefficient about it. You might be able to sort in Django directly, but then you'll need to provide us with more information about the models (you said you're multiplying one with another)

Comment: @Martin you don't need to make the `dict`, just `.sort` the list of tuples from `zip`.

Comment: Could you elaborate this `zip` thingy - I know that this function exists but I don't use it, because I don't know how it works :) Can Matplolib iterate over the keys and the values? I never tried this

Comment: cool stuff, even better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jonrsharpe and martin I found the answer and i like to share it:

```
#Zip the list
sort_year = list(zip(values, labels))
#Sortig the list
sort_year.sort()
#pitfall: the list will be in reversed order
values, labels = zip(*sort_year)
```

There you go - sorted from most to least - iam totaly amazed!

Answer (score 1):

I believe another possible solution is to use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
values   = np.array(values)
labels   = np.array(labels)
sort_vec = np.argsort( values )[::-1]
values   = values[ sort_vec ]
labels   = labels[ sort_vec ]
```